# visual basic - MessageBox not appearing

Tags: vb.net

For some reason, my messageBox does not appear! can someone help me :

code:

```vb
item = InputBox("What is the item?", "InputBox Test", "Type the item here.")
If item = "shoe" Then
    Dim connStr As String = ""
    Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    connection.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "UPDATE table set item = noOfItems+1 where username= '" & Login.txtusername.Text & "'"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    If (READER.Read() = True) Then
        Query = "select * from table where username= '" & Login.txtusername.Text & " '"
        Dim noOfItems As Integer
        Dim username As String
        noOfItems = READER("noOfItems")
        username = READER("username")
        MessageBox.Show(username & "- The number of items you have is: " & noOfItems)
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("Unlucky, Incorrect item. Please see hints. Your score still remains the same")
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `"For some reason"` - This sounds like an *excellent* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  It allows you to step through your code, line by line as it executes, and observe the behaviors and runtime values of your variables.  This will allow you to determine the logical path that the code is actually taking so you can see *why* it isn't reaching the line of code that you expect it to.  We can help answer that "why" if you can provide us with information about it.  But we can't debug your code on your computer for you.

Comment: The ability to debug is ***essential***.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim item As Object
Dim Command As MySqlCommand
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
Dim connection As MySqlConnection
Dim Query As String
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        item = InputBox("What is the item?", "InputBox Test", "Type the item here.")
        If item = "shoe" Then
            Dim connStr As String = ""
            Dim connection As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
            connection.Open()
            Query = "select * from table where username= '" & txtusername.Text & " '"
            READER = Command.ExecuteReader
            If READER.HasRows Then
                Dim noOfItems As Integer
                Dim username As String
                noOfItems = READER("noOfItems") + 1
                username = READER("username")
                Query = "UPDATE table set item = '" & noOfItems & "' where username= '" & txtusername.Text & "'"
                Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, connection)
                Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show(username & "- The number of items you have is: " & noOfItems)
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox("Unlucky, Incorrect item. Please see hints. Your score still remains the same")
        End If
        connection.close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: hey @mysta thanks for the reply! however i forgot to mention , i already have initialised the item and command in the public class segment.

Comment: Solved the message box appearing ( however doesn't show the incremented value now from the query) - p.s i really appreciate the help @mysta

Comment: unfortunately i get an error message displaying now @mysta

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Error") change to MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)